# Limited permissions on linux

Tags: linux, security, permissions

I want to give a specific user on Linux some privileges to enable him to run commands like `shutdown` or `apt-get`. I don't want to use the SUID bit since there are other users that I don't want to let them use these commands.

How do I do something like this?

Comment: The non-programming answer is to install and configure `sudo`. If that what you need (it is) then this is off-topic and should be closed (not migrated all the appropriate sites already have a version of this question). If you want a programming solution you should be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` would probably be the easiest way to do this.  You'll want to add something like the following to the sudoers file

```
username   ALL=(ALL) /sbin/shutdown, /usr/bin/apt-get
```

where username is replaced with the user's actual username.  You should be able to google for some examples - here is [one such page](http://aplawrence.com/Basics/sudo.html).

Editing the sudoers file can be done safely by using the `visudo` program.